How do I fix Pods update to recommended settings after every flutter build on macOS?
I have been developing a flutter web app for a few years without issue until I decided to refactor it as a native macos app.
Here is a summary of the issues I have faced and how I got around most of them. The journey is far from over.
Out of the box, unable to find pods output files. The fix is to import the files in AppInfo.xcconfig.
I get header issues on build like this:
Pods/GoogleDataTransport/GoogleDataTransport/GDTCCTLibrary/Protogen/nanopb/compliance.nanopb.h:22:

Pods/nanopb/pb_decode.h:9:10: error: 'pb.h' file not found with <angled> include; use "quotes" instead

To get round this I need to run this script before every build:
pod deintegrate
rm -rf Pods
rm Podfile.lock
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos
pod setup
pod install --repo-update

I can't build 2 times consecutively without that. Then I can build but flutter run has 2 errors and produces a black screen.
I also need to run a prebuild and after build script to fix headers in the Runner target build phases.
Here is my post build script, they are similar
#!/bin/sh

# Paths to nanopb headers
NANOPB_HEADERS=(
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/nanopb/pb_common.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/nanopb/pb_decode.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/nanopb/pb_encode.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/nanopb/pb.h"
)

# Paths to PromisesObjC headers
PROMISES_HEADERS=(
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+All.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Always.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Any.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Async.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Await.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Catch.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Delay.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Do.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Race.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Recover.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Reduce.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Retry.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Testing.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Then.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Timeout.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Validate.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise+Wrap.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromise.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromises.h"
  "${SRCROOT}/Pods/PromisesObjC/Sources/FBLPromises/include/FBLPromiseError.h"
)

# Replace double-quoted includes with angle-bracketed includes in nanopb headers
for HEADER in "${NANOPB_HEADERS[@]}"; do
  if [ -f "$HEADER" ]; then
    sed -i '' 's/#include "\([^"]*\)"/#include <\1>/g' "$HEADER"
  fi
done

# Replace double-quoted includes with angle-bracketed includes in PromisesObjC headers
for HEADER in "${PROMISES_HEADERS[@]}"; do
  if [ -f "$HEADER" ]; then
    sed -i '' 's/#include "\([^"]*\)"/#include <\1>/g' "$HEADER"
  fi
done

Even with all this effort Xcode reports that Pods always needs updating after a build. I also see that MainFlutterWindow.swift complains about not finding the FlutterMacOS framework even though AppDelegate.swift needs it and can see it.
I have spent a week trying to resolve these issues and about to give up on Apple dev unless I can find a solution. Cocopods just seems too fragile to use.
Mac m2 version 14.6, Flutter 3.22.3.

Please try upgrading your cocoapods to the latest version e.g. 1.10 or 1.15, or updating to the pre-release version as seen in this SO question
